# Testing silent push notifications in Xcode11.4 beta

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to test notifications in Xcode 11.4 simulator and everything works well except silent notifications. **didReceiveRemoteNotification**  is not triggered.

What I've done:

Enabled Push Notifications in Background Modes/Remote Notifications in Capabilities

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, _ in
        if granted {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In **didReceiveRemoteNotification** I just set value in UserDefaults to use it later

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
    UserDefaults.standard.set("Hello world", forKey: "hello")
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

And then in **sceneDidBecomeActive** what to read this value from UserDefaults

```
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "hello")) // always nil
}
```

This is my .apns json

```
{
"Simulator Target Bundle": "xxx",
 "aps" : {
    "content-available" : 1
 }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

It appears that, presumably due to a bug (that I believe has been reported), the apns file is resulting in `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` being called, rather than `didReceiveRemoteNotification` being called.

Comment: Hi, how do you handle the notification inside performFetchWithCompletionHandler as it hasn't the userInfo which contains the notification?

Answer (score 6):

Jeff's Solution worked for Me, In addition I had to add 'Background Fetch' mode to app

[image: Enable Background Fetch]